# Windows 8 copying issues

Tags: windows-8, filesystem-corruption

I recently formatted my laptop and installed Windows 8 Pro (it was Windows 7 Pro before format), now I am receiving a lot of weird issues when copying files onto the laptop.

Issue 1:

When copying a large folder from my external to my music folder it start calculating but after a few minutes it says Can't find the source file on disk. Even if I try again it still gives me the same problem and I don't think it has something to do with the external as i have copied other large folders without issues.

Issue 2:

In my download folder I have a lot of sub folders, when I try to move a .avi file from the Downloads folder Downloads\Movies I get the error that The file or folder is in use by another program, but then I copy another .avi to the Downloads\Movies folder an it works fine, and if I then try the original .avi again it works fine.

Any ideas what might be causing this or should I just try to re-format?

Comment: Issue 2 could be due to windows is actually trying to read the movie file trying to determine some information out of the movie. Both Win7 (and I'm guessing Win8) has that feature (I think windows trying to find out the movie length but it may find other things as well). So when you go into that folder for the first time, that is what it is doing. Hence why when you leave it for a while, and then copy, it will work when windows is 'finished' with the file. About your Issue 1, my current guess is the ext HDD may be dying. Try copying small amount at a time. Just in case.